# Faster directory/file navigation with :NERDTree and/or :sex in vim

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is there a simple way to navigate based on directory name or even moving by  directories or files either up or down with the :sex or :NERDTree vim directory browsers?

Comment: It maybe helpful to give us examples so we can help you better. Also you can use `/` in those buffers. I also suggest a good fuzzy finder like CtrlP

Comment: Ah / and then <Enter>. I had tried it with / o in NERDTree, but it didn't work. / <Enter> did just what I wanted. Thanks for the nudge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above: If you use the slash character for find, type all or part of the file or directory name until the resource you are interested in is highlighted, then press Enter, it will open it - either by expanding a directory in the tree view, or by opening the file for editing in a separate pane.  Thanks Peter for encouraging me to explore the slash in this context a bit more :)